# How to use Akka Cluster to consume Kafka topic with multiple partitions

Tags: scala, partition, consumer, apache-kafka, akka-cluster

I'm going to write a scala program to consume Kafka messages, convert it to another format and post it to external service. To add scalability, I want to use Akka Cluster to consume messages in different partitions in parallel. That is launch the same number of consumers and partitions. I'm appreciate if anyone can give me a guide or code snippet, thanks!